# How to "Print when" with condition

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a question, I have a subreport that prints many lines because it is in the detail band, for me this is fine, but I want to filter the rows based on parameters when I print the report, I used the option "print when" to set the Boolean condition but not it works, this works with only one parameter.

The condition is:

```
(!"N".equals($P{Chk_Amministratori})
|| ($F{field1} != $P{CheckDinamico1}
|| $F{field1} != $P{CheckDinamico2}
|| $F{field1} != $P{CheckDinamico3}
|| $F{field1} != $P{CheckDinamico4}
|| $F{field1} != $P{CheckDinamico5}
|| $F{field1} != $P{CheckDinamico6}
|| $F{field1} != $P{CheckDinamico7}
|| $F{field1} != $P{CheckDinamico8}
|| $F{field1} != $P{CheckDinamico10}) ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE
```

If I put a parameter it works, for example

$F{field1} != $P{CheckDinamico10} ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `$F{field1} != $P{CheckDinamico10} ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE` - this is valid syntax, BTW you can use privitive boolean type. Maybe you are comparing objects wrong (I don't know the type of fields and parameters)

Comment: The field is always the same, but multiple values of that field are passed in the subreport and I want to parameterize these values that I pass so that I can only see those at which I pass the exact value.

Answer (score 0):

The logic in your expressions is flawed.  You have this

```
$F{field1} != $P{CheckDinamico1}
|| $F{field1} != $P{CheckDinamico2}
|| ...
```

Let's say CheckDinamico1 is 5 and CheckDinamico2 is 7.  So your expressions is field1 != 5 OR field1 != 7 OR ..

This expression is true whatever the value of field1.  If field1 is 3, it will be different from both 5 and 7, so the expression is true.  If fiedl1 is 5, it will be different from 7, and because of OR the expression will also be true.  And if field1 is 7, it will be different from 5 so again the expression is true.

Maybe you wanted AND instead of OR in the expression?  Also, as [Alex K](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61381340/how-to-print-when-with-condition#comment108593188_61381340) noted, `!=` might not always work so it's safer to use `equals`, and you can use primitive boolean expressions, you don't need `Boolean`.  Therefore try something like this:

```
(!"N".equals($P{Chk_Amministratori})
|| (!$F{field1}.equals($P{CheckDinamico1})
&& !$F{field1}.equals($P{CheckDinamico2})
&& !$F{field1}.equals($P{CheckDinamico3})
&& !$F{field1}.equals($P{CheckDinamico4})
&& !$F{field1}.equals($P{CheckDinamico5})
&& !$F{field1}.equals($P{CheckDinamico6})
&& !$F{field1}.equals($P{CheckDinamico7})
&& !$F{field1}.equals($P{CheckDinamico8})
&& !$F{field1}.equals($P{CheckDinamico10}))
```

Comment: Thank you dada67, I try your solution it is exactly. Thank you